# failing to authenticate with spring security

Tags: authentication, grails, spring-security

I'm running grails 2.3.3 and I've successfully added the spring-security-core, version 2.0-RC5 plugin, into my application. And I am successfully logging into the application with the new user/roles built setup using s2-quickstart.

As guided by the a number of videos tutorials I've created a home and public controller and managed to access the action based URLS using on different levels of authentication.

My problem is harnessing this authentication with the original application views/actions in controllers that existed prior to introducing the security plugin. When trying to access any of these URLS I get the message:

> Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.

To enable authentication on an individual action of a controllers I've added at the top of the controller file:

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
```

And then directly Above the action definition of each individual action I've added the line:

```
@Secured('ROLE_USER')
```

or

```
@Secured('ROLE_ADMIN')
```

I've also added high-level authentication controls in springsecurity staticRules of the Config.groovy file:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
'/logout/**':                  ['permitAll'],
'/videos/**':                  ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
'/videoNew/inputvideo':                  ['permitAll']
```

I thought it maybe that I need to recreate these original controllers since adding the security plugin but I'm still not able to get past the authentication hurdle.

What a I missing?

Here are all the grails.plugin.springSecurity settings in the Config.groovy file that were setup by s2-quickstart:

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'vidplay.SecUser'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'vidplay.SecUserSecRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'vidplay.SecRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/home' //SEC0616 defines default page to go upon a successfull login
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
'/':                ['permitAll'],
'/index':           ['permitAll'],
'/index.gsp':       ['permitAll'],
'/assets/**':       ['permitAll'],
'/**/js/**':        ['permitAll'],
'/**/css/**':       ['permitAll'],
'/**/images/**':    ['permitAll'],
'/**/favicon.ico':  ['permitAll'],
'/dbconsole/**':                  ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
'/videos/**':                  ['permitAll'],
'/public/**':                  ['permitAll'],
'/videos/index':                  ['permitAll'],
'/home/**':                  ['permitAll'],
'/login/**':                  ['permitAll'],
'/logout/**':                  ['permitAll'],
'/videos/**':                  ['ROLE_ADMIN'],
'/videoNew/inputvideo':                  ['permitAll']

 ]
```

Here is the spring security debug log indicating **'Authorization successful'** - despite that I'm still access problems:

> matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher Request '/videonew/inputvideo' matched by universal pattern '/**'
>   web.FilterChainProxy /videoNew/inputvideo at position 1 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
>   context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@bdd2c1f3: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bdd2c1f3: Principal: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@6315afb: Username: mike1; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffe9938: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 02E339B19772D3DF9B32723AC1EA8E3F; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'
>   web.FilterChainProxy /videoNew/inputvideo at position 2 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
>   web.FilterChainProxy /videoNew/inputvideo at position 3 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter'
>   web.FilterChainProxy /videoNew/inputvideo at position 4 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
>   web.FilterChainProxy /videoNew/inputvideo at position 5 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
>   web.FilterChainProxy /videoNew/inputvideo at position 6 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
>   web.FilterChainProxy /videoNew/inputvideo at position 7 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
>   web.FilterChainProxy /videoNew/inputvideo at position 8 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
>   intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /videoNew/inputvideo; Attributes: [permitAll]
>   intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bdd2c1f3: Principal: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@6315afb: Username: mike1; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffe9938: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 02E339B19772D3DF9B32723AC1EA8E3F; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
>   hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_USER] one can reach [ROLE_USER] in zero or more steps.
>   intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor Authorization successful
>   intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
>   web.FilterChainProxy /videoNew/inputvideo reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
>   access.ExceptionTranslationFilter Chain processed normally
>   context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed

Comment: What's the value of the `grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType` in your configuration file?

Comment: @ylima there are not settings for securityConfigType - I've added all the spring security plugin settings in the Config above. There is also a file: **DefaulfSecurityConfig.groovy** in the conf folder. Which makes reference to various options - what do you suggest?

Comment: @ylima I've set the securityConfigType to 'Annotation' although I believe that this is the default anyway. I have switched on the spring security debug logging by adding : `debug 'org.springframework.security'` into the log4j block in Config.groovy. I can then compare the logs of a successful access to the home/index view and the failure to access the  /videos/inputvideo view. Surprisingly, they both are identical stating that Authorization successful' . Is there some other setting I need to make before it will display any view despite the authorization?

Comment: @ylime - Looking at the debug logs further I can see that there is a redirection taking place in the application to a different view which needed to be configured with the spring security setting. All okay now - once the securityConfigType has been set.